# Creating pubsub subscription to topic failed with error: User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

When I try to deploy a dataflow job with a service account, it fails with the following error:

> Workflow failed. Causes: Step
>   "setup_resource_XXXXXX.subscription-1210256155950706891639" failed.,
>   Step setup_resource_XXXXXX.subscription-1210256155950706891639: Set up
>   of resource XXXXXX.subscription-12102561559507068916 failed, Creating 
>   pubsub subscription
>   projects/XXXXXX/subscriptions/XXXXXX.subscription-12102561559507068916
>   to topic projects/XXXXXX/topics/XXXXXX failed with error: User not
>   authorized to perform this action.

I have given the service account "Pub/Sub Subscriber" permission for that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the similar issue when I used PubSub to Cloud Storage (Text) template of dataflow job, I had to give **pub/sub subscriber **and** pub/sub viewer** roles to my controller service account of dataflow on pubsub topic and **Storage Object Admin** role on the bucket to the same controller service account of dataflow.
It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Dataflow is trying to create a subscription here :

> **Creating pubsub subscription** projects/XXXXXX/subscriptions/XXXXXX.subscription-12102561559507068916

However, role `roles/pubsub.subscriber` is not sufficient to create subscriptions, because it does not have `pubsub.subscriptions.create` permission.

You might need to grant your service account the role `roles/pubsub.editor` instead (`pubsub.subscriptions.create` permissions is assigned to that role).

Comment: I tried with "Pub/Sub Editor" permission. it didn't worked.

Comment: Does the subscription exist before the Dataflow job is launched? Could you edit your question and share your code (at least the part where you read data from PubSub)?

Comment: I am using the template Cloud_PubSub_to_GCS_Text. The subscription did not exist.

Comment: Does the Dataflow job belongs to the same project as the topic?

Comment: Is the service account you're using the default one or a service account you have created?

Comment: The pubsub topic is from the same project. I have created the service account.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the Dataflow job with the default service account? Just to ensure that the problem comes from the service account you have created and its permissions.

Comment: I don't have any default service account for dataflow.

Comment: If you start the job without specifying one, it will use a "default" one.

Comment: Then, just compare the permissions between the default service account and your service account and you should find what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of norbjb(Jun 3 '19 at 12:56), I have found that your Service Account need be granted:

Cloud Dataflow Service Agent

That solved the issue for me.